# Does a specific indie game merit a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a few questions about a specific indie game. Does that merit a tag for the game? How big/popular does a game need to be to merit its own tag, rather than the collective [indie-rpg]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's a public game, or even a public beta game, then yes it should have a tag.  If it never gets another question the tag will eventually drop off ...

*I'm looking at you [maid](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maid).*

Comment: The game is still supported and has a fanbase. Stranger things have happened….

Comment: +1 Every game (or perhaps game line) should def. have a tag!

Comment: @CRoss' point is that tags on SE sites autoexpire and get deleted if they aren't used more than once. Regardless of validity and merit, if it's the only shock question then the tag will die eventually.

Comment: Hmmm. How long does that take? Does that leave the question untagged?

Comment: @Standback 90 days I think, and it can.  Usually there are other tags on a question, and people are free to add it back.

Comment: Tags used on only one question are purged after 6 months. See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/922/why-are-some-questions-tagged-with-untagged and on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418

Comment: A tag wiki prevents the deletion

Answer (score 4):

Is the indie-rpg tag even useful?  I would like to get rid of it.

Comment: okeefe - it is useful, particularly for games that do not get a lot of questions. Stack Exchange automagically prunes tags every 6ish months and tags that don't meet a certain quota are removed. indie keeps those questions from becoming untagged.

Comment: That's an excellent reason.  Is there a way to selectively disable that?

Comment: not that I know of.